# Cesium large number of entity updates

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am working on a project dealing with sensor data.  In my backend everything is stored in a database which is getting polled by a controller and converted into kml to display on the cesium globe.  This poll happens every 5-10 seconds and contains around 4000-8000 objects (we store up to 1 minute worth of data so we are looking at somewhere like 20k - 50k points).  Following this I have an update function which slowly fades the markers out which updates every 5 seconds.

To load the kml on the map I use the following function:

```
var dataSource = new Cesium.KmlDataSource();
dataSource.load('link').then(function(value);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
});
```

On the update color function I am iterating over all of the objects within the datasources entity collection and updating them like so (this is very inefficient):

```
var colorUpdate = Cesium.Color.fromAlpha(newColor, .4);
dataSource.entities.values[i].billboard.color = colorUpdate;
```

When I do and add or color update I see a large amount of lag and was curious if there was anything you would suggest to fix this?  Generally I get a freeze up for a few seconds.  After 60 seconds of the data being on the map it gets removed like so (just a different if case within the color update loop)

```
dataSource.entities.remove(dataSource.entities.values[i]);
```

**Is there potentially a way to set a propertiy for an entire entity collection so when this collection becomes 30 seconds old it updates the color to a new one?  It seems that I just need to find a way to set a property for the entire collection vs individual entities.  Does anyone know how to do that or have a suggestion for something better?**

Comment: It would help to see a bigger part of your code. There are several directions I can think of - which you might have already tried.

Do you update 4000-8000 entities every 5-10 seconds? And only the color changes? 

How many entities do you show at the same time on the map?